# How to operate with the variables that the user decide?

Tags: java, eclipse, int, syntax-error

I was trying to create a simple java code that works like that:

- The system sets some variables, for example: G = 1; F = 2; E = 4;..etc
- The system ask to the user "Which variables you want to use?" and he writes for example, G + F.
- The system operate with the variables, in this case, the system will show "3".

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumaNumeros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int A = 64;
       int B = 32;
       int C = 16;
       int D = 8;
       int E = 4;
       int F = 2;
       int G = 1;
       System.out.println("Which variables you want to use?");
       Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
       int N = number.nextInt();
       System.out.print("The number is" + N + "!");
    }
}
```

And the error

```
Which variables you want to use?
A+B
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at SumaNumeros.main(SumaNumeros.java:14)
```

I need help, thanks if someone get to make it work.

Comment: That exception is because you pass a String, but you want to get an integer: `int N = number.nextInt();`.

Comment: Yes, I know but I want to know how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

You could of course do it yourself - something like this:

```
String varName = number.next();
int N;
if(varName.equals("A")) N = A;
else if(varName.equals("B")) N = B;
else if(varName.equals("C")) N = C;
// and so on
else {
    System.out.println("That wasn't a valid variable name.");
    return;
}
```

Or you could use a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> variables = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("A", 64);
variables.put("B", 32);
// and so on

String varName = number.next();
int N = variables.get(varName);
```

Comment: Okey, I will try using Map.. let's see what happen. Thanks!

Comment: Okey it works, but not exactly as you said! Thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of making it work:
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class SumaNumeros {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("A" , 64);
    map.put("B" , 32);
    map.put("C", 16);
    map.put("D", 8);
    map.put("E", 4);
    map.put("F", 2);
    map.put("G",1);
    System.out.println("Which variables you want to use?");
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = number.nextLine();
    if (answer.indexOf('+')==-1){
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
    String first = answer.substring(0, answer.indexOf('+'));
    String second = answer.substring(answer.indexOf('+')+1, answer.length());
    if (map.containsKey(first) && map.containsKey(second)){
        System.out.print("The number is " + (map.get(first) + map.get(second)) + "!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");            
    }
    number.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: I have got make it work for my own using the first answer, and your code doesn't work. Thanks anyway! :D